# Jaccard Distance in R package philentropy vs. proxy

Tags: r, proxy, distance

When I compute Jaccard Distances for objects in a data frame I get confused by comparing the results of proxy::dist() and philentropy::distance().
Additionally, both results are not in accord with what I would expect (so I guess, the confusion is caused by me and not by the packages).

Here is a MWE for binary coded data with some comments in it. proxy and philentropy are nearly the same, even though there are missings in the philentropy distance matrix.

```
rm(list=ls())

library("philentropy")
library("proxy")

#5 objects and 2 variables (binary coded) 
data01 <- data.frame(var1 = c(0,1,0,0,1), 
                     var2 = c(0,1,0,0,0))

# jaccard-distand of object A and B:= 1-(count(A equals B) / count(A + B)
# example jaccard-distance 
# object 1 and 2: no correspondance, maximum distance = 1
# object 1 and 3: same coding, minimum distance = 0
# object 1 and 5: different coding on variable 1 and same coding on     variable 2, medium distance = .5

Stats01 <- dist(data01, method="binary", diag=TRUE, upper = TRUE)
Proxy01 <- proxy::dist(data01, method="jaccard", diag=TRUE, upper = TRUE)
Philentropy01 <- philentropy::distance(data01, method="jaccard")

Stats01 #maximum distance object 1 and object 2 (as expected), but object 1 and object 5 as well maximum distance
Proxy01 #same results as Stats01
Philentropy01 #NaN for most zero-values



    1   2   3   4   5
1 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
2 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.5
3 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
4 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
5 1.0 0.5 1.0 1.0 0.0


    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
v1 NaN 1.0 NaN NaN 1.0
v2   1 0.0   1   1 0.5
v3 NaN 1.0 NaN NaN 1.0
v4 NaN 1.0 NaN NaN 1.0
v5   1 0.5   1   1 0.0
```

Here is a MWE for coded data with values 1, 2, 3. proxy and philentropy are different and both are different from what I expected.

```
#5 objects and 2 variables (three categories coded starting from 1)
data123 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,3,1,2), 
                      var2 = c(1,2,3,1,1))

Stats123 <- dist(data123, method="binary", diag=TRUE, upper = TRUE)
Proxy123 <- proxy::dist(data123, method="jaccard", diag=TRUE, upper = TRUE)
Philentropy123 <- philentropy::distance(data123, method="jaccard")

Stats123 #only zero-distances, it's a pitty, but expected because binary interprets everything not-zero as 1
Proxy123 #same results as Stats123
Philentropy123 #for object 1 I expected same distance to object 2 and 3

  1 2 3 4 5
1 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0 0


          v1        v2        v3        v4        v5
v1 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.5714286 0.0000000 0.2500000
v2 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.1428571 0.3333333 0.1428571
v3 0.5714286 0.1428571 0.0000000 0.5714286 0.3571429
v4 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.5714286 0.0000000 0.2500000
v5 0.2500000 0.1428571 0.3571429 0.2500000 0.0000000
```

I'd like to know:

1. Why does philentropy give NaN-values for some zero distances (and how to avoid them) in the case of binary coded data?
2. Why does correspondance lead to different distance values depending on whether zeros or 1 are in accord, or for the variables with 1, 2, 3 coding depending on these values.

Comment: Thanks to a personal communication with Hajk Drost - the author of the philentropy package - the two questions are answered now. I was in error with respect to the interpretation of the input data. So the answer to question 2 is: Input is used as count data and not as nominal coded data. One may use philentropy::distance(data123, method = "jaccard", est.prob = "empirical”) to scale counts from 0 to 1. More details are found here [link](http://csis.pace.edu/ctappert/dps/d861-12/session4-p2.pdf)